# How to get all the line number of a variable from source code given LLVM IR?

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

I am totally a newbie in LLVM. I wanted to know how we can get all the line numbers for a particular variable from source code given LLVM IR?

For example (showing snippet of LLVM IR)

```
store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4, !dbg !12
!12 = !DILocation(line: 2, column: 6, scope: !7)
%4 = load i32*, i32** %ip, align 8, !dbg !30
!30 = !DILocation(line: 7, column: 4, scope: !25)
```

I believe, from inspecting LLVM IR, getting the line number details for any variable has something to do with accessing `!dbg` at the end of instruction. But I don't know how to access those information.

Another doubt is if a pointer is used to store address of a variable, how do we know for which variable it is storing address of?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe, from inspecting LLVM IR, getting the line number details
>   for any variable has something to do with accessing !dbg at the end of
>   instruction. But I don't know how to access this information.

I believe you are correct in that assumption. As far as I can tell, all the information is there for you:

The first instruction ends with `!dbg !12` (`store i32 0, i32* %i, align 4, !dbg !12`).

Then you should find a line starting with `!12`. Hint, the debug info is usually at the bottom of the LLVM IR for the module.

In your case it is: `!12 = !DILocation(line: 2, column: 6, scope: !7)` <-- The interpretation here is: The instruction marked with `!12` comes from line 2 column 6 in the source file that generated this LLVM IR. The name of the source file should also be available (usually at the top of the LLVM IR).

> Another doubt is if a pointer is used to store address of a variable,
>   how do we know for which variable it is storing address of ?

You need to deduce that information yourself e.g. through data flow analysis. It's conceptually fairly simple though, since [LLVM IR is in SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) already.

Comment: The answer is correct, but might mention [Instruction::getDebugLoc()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#ab4f3bf98b5054831b608852e33427814). BTW, the line that starts with !7 will have the file name. Or one can get it from the DebugLoc object, that's what the IR printer does.

Comment: Thanks Morten and arnt for your answer, I see that through I->getDebugLoc() we can get details about the line number of the variable but my concern is how to get all the lines where it is accessed?

Answer (score 0):

Everything in LLVM is a Value, and some of the Values keep track of their users. 42 (a constant int) does not, but the Values you are interested in do keep track of their users. I have some code that processes the phi nodes that use a partciular Value; here are three lines that find those phi nodes:

```
for(auto u : someValue->users()) {
  PHINode * phi = dyn_cast<PHINode>(u);
  if(phi)
    …
```

Note that this only works in-module. If you have a global value (such as many functions) then uses from outside the module aren't tracked (such as most function calls).